# Multiplying a factorial with non factorial

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to understand the following equation, do I multiply the 2 and the 1 to get (n+2)! ?

$$(n+2)(n+1)! = (n+2)!$$

Comment: Try dividing $(n+2)!$ by $(n+1)!$ using whatever definition you have for the factorial function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quiet simple: $$\color{#C00}{(n+1)!}\cdot(n+2)=\color{#C00}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n\cdot(n+1)}\cdot(n+2)=(n+2)!$$

Comment: Okay, so basically its just adding one more to the factorial, thanks for visualizing that